# Why is systemd CPUQuota setting not visible in any <show> listings?

Tags: linux, services, cpu-usage, systemd, resources

If I show the settings of my clamav systemd services, they do not display a CPUQuota setting. They display only CPUQuotaPerSecUSec settings.

```
._. systemctl show clamav* --all | grep CPUQuota
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPeriodUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPeriodUSec=infinity
```

(`--all` shows empty settings that might otherwise be left out of the output).

Whereas:

```
systemctl show clamav* --property=CPUQuota
```

...produces blank output.

And in fact, no systemd service has a CPUQuota set or even apparent at all in its listing, as you may see if you run:

```
._. for u in $(systemctl list-units --type service --plain --quiet | awk '{ print $1 }'); do systemctl show "$u" | grep CPUQ; done
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPeriodUSec=infinity
CPUQuotaPerSecUSec=infinity
...
```

Advisories on controlling systemd processes recommend setting a CPUQuota setting. This setting is indeed listed in the systemd.resource-control manpage. The manpage says `CPUQuotaPerSecUSec` and `CPUQuotaPerPeriodUSec` are set parameters for CPUQuota.

But why would it appear not to be set in the service listing, even with some default? Is the option to set it deprecated?

Answer (score 2):

CPUQuota is listed in a `systemctl show` command as `CPUQuotaPerSecUSec` (`USec` means microseconds, but it's displayed in milliseconds).  10% is displayed as 100ms.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).